# Intermediate CA rotation and issued CRL

Tags: certificate, x509certificate, pki, ca

Let assume following scenario:

1. Root CA issued Intermediate1 (valid for a long time, longer than rotation period).
2. Intermediate1 issued one CRL "Crl1"
3. Intermediate1 issued two certificates: LeafA, LeafB - both of them points to Crl1 as CDP.
4. LeafA has been revoked by placing it on Crl1.
5. Verification check of LeafA failed - as expected due to its revocation.
6. Now, Root CA requires me to rotate Intermediate1 to Intermediate2 - and I cannot use Intermediate1 to sign anything (new certs, or next crls) at all.
7. I need to refresh Crl1 now. **How can I do that?**

   - I cannot use Intermediate1.
   - I cannot use Intermediate2 as issuer of CRL won't match LeafA issuer.
   - I cannot either revoke LeafB as cannot use Intermediate1 nor Intermediate2 due to above bullets.

Comment: `I cannot use Intermediate1.` -- why? CA rotation doesn't imply that you cannot use previous CA versions to sign CRLs, in fact, multiple versions of CA can co-exist.

Comment: The instant __LeafA__ was revoked, __Intermediate1__ should have published a CRL to cater for these scenarios.  Or, more realistically, a catastrophic failure of __Intermediate1__.  You need to escalate to the Policy Management Authority (PMA) (I assume you have one) as Root's stance is compromising your security.  If the PMA made the decision that you must rotate before the CRL is issued, then on their heads be it.  Get it in writing though!